# JavaScript game Collision

Tags: javascript, collision, game-physics

In a linear fighting game i use bellow formula for getting X collision and Y collision (when character jump on top of another fighter ).
I really dont know whats wrong in this formula , because i get some nonsense logical error in my game .(when collision happen , i step character forward and backward, so i get nonsense position sometimes.
beside my formula if you have any other formula, please share it. thanks

```
    if (this.x < secondPlayer.x + secondPlayer.width + this.border &&
        this.x + this.width + this.border > secondPlayer.x && this.y < secondPlayer.y + secondPlayer.height + this.border &&
        this.height + this.y + this.border > secondPlayer.y && this.x != secondPlayer.x){
            return 'x';
        }
        else if (this.x == secondPlayer.x && this.y < secondPlayer.y + secondPlayer.height + this.border &&
            this.height + this.y + this.border > secondPlayer.y) {
                return 'y';
     }else{
         return 'n';
     }
```

Comment: is `this.border` a scalar value (e.g., 23.4) or an object?

Comment: Please explain what "border" stands for. Also, you need more parenthesis in you conditions!

Comment: yep its value (not object)  for border of character .

Comment: @NicolasCailloux: i have no syntax error , but i think may in Y collision , some logic issues , as it must be on top of character .

Comment: Unit tests might highlight the issue? You can generate test data meeting each of the conditions within the if and then mix and match them for a different set of conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have time to give you a precise answer, just to redirect you to [bounding boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection). Define a structure like a rectangle and check borders as in the link:

```
myBox.x = this.x 
myBox.y = this.y
myBox.width = this.width + this.border
myBox.height = this.height + this.border
```

You can also have a different approach:

```
myBox.left = this.x 
myBox.top = this.y
myBox.right = this.x + this.width + this.border
myBox.bottom = this.y + this.height + this.border
```

and check: 
my left against opponent's right, my top against opponent's bottom, and inverted.

Edit: 
with your code, you cannot have both collisions checked: you code says:

`if (x collides) return 'x' else if (y collides) return 'y'`

So if you have an 'x' collision the function returns and doesn't check for 'y'. 
Moreover, in second test I think `this.x == secondPlayer.x` is wrong : 'y' collision is checked only when both players have the same position. But they can overlap without being on the same 'x' (for instance, I jumped and fall in the middle of opponent's sprite)!

Comment: this is almost same as my X collision only , as i explain in commit , i have Y collision in top of character too. it means i should get Y collision + x collision